# Formula for distribution of quotient of random variables, why is my derivation incorrect?

Tags: probability

Given two real valued independent random variables $X$ and $Y$, write their ratio as $R = \frac{X}{Y}$

I know various other ways of finding a formula for the distribution of $R$, but I'm specifically interested in understanding why the following derivation does not yield the correct result.

$$
P(R = r) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} P(\frac{X}{Y} = r | X = x)P(X = x)dx \\
= \int_{\mathbb{R}}P(Y = \frac{x}{r})P(X = x)dx \\
= \int_{\mathbb{R}}f_Y(\frac{x}{r})f_X(x)dx
$$

I can't see how this is wrong.

Comment: Each equality you wrote is incorrect. Why should the result be correct?

Comment: The distribution function should be $Pr[R \leq r]$.  If $R$ has a continuous CDF then $Pr[R=r]=0$.  The formula you want is $$Pr[R\leq r] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} Pr[R\leq r|X=x]f_X(x)dx$$

Comment: Can you not obtain a density function by conditioning?

Comment: @zhoraster Actually, for continuous random variables, every equality before the last one is correct and equivalent to `0 = 0`... :-)

Comment: @RJTK : Good work (I think zhoraster posted your work as a new answer).  I have some minor corrections for problem 4, see my comments there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your posted computations seem to blur the distinctions between $Pr[X=x]$ and $f_X(x)$.  For example, $Pr[X=x]$ is a number in $[0,1]$, while $f_X(x)$ can be larger than 1 for some values of $x$.

---

A correct way of obtaining the probability of an event by conditioning is:

$$ Pr[R\leq r] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} Pr[R \leq r|X=x]f_X(x)dx \quad (Eq 1)$$

For a similar equation with densities, you can take a derivative of (Eq 1) with respect to $r$:

$$ f_R(r) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{R|X=x}(r|X=x)f_X(x)dx $$

The conditional density $f_{R|X=x}(r|X=x)$ is not the same as $f_Y(x/r)$. You can compute $f_{R|X=x}(r|X=x)$ by working with $Pr[R \leq r|X=x]$ before taking derivatives.

---

Homework questions for you (can you post answers to them?):

1) Give an example of a random variable $W$ with a density $f_W(w)$ that can be larger than 1 for certain values of $w$.

2) Obtain an expression for $Pr[R\leq r]$ similar to (Eq 1), but this time conditioning on $Y=y$.

3) Assume $Y$ is a positive random variable. Compute $f_{R|Y=y}(r|Y=y)$ by starting with $Pr[R\leq r|Y=y]$, manipulating this, and taking a derivative.

4) Assume $Y$ is a positive random variable.  Compute $f_{R|X=x}(r|X=x)$ by starting with $Pr[R\leq r|X=x]$.  (Remember that multiplying by negative numbers flips inequalities. If it helps, at first you can assume that $r>0$.)

Comment: +1 for the hw part (I am curious to see what will come out of this worthy try).

Comment: I made an edit to the original answer for the homework problems.  It is awaiting peer review.

Comment: @RJTK, instead of editing the answer, always post your answer separately.

Answer (score 1):

---

Sol'n, written by original asker

1) $U([0, \frac{1}{2}])$, density is 2 for values on it's support

2) $P(R \le r) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}P(R \le r | Y = y)f_Y(y)dy = \int_{\mathbb{R}}P(X\le ry)f_Y(y)dy$, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

3) $f_{R|Y = y} = \frac{d}{dr}P(R \le r | Y = y) = \frac{d}{dr}P(X \le ry) = yf_X(ry)$

4) 
$$
f_{R|X = x}(r | X = x) = \frac{d}{dr}P(R \le r | X = x) = \\
\frac{d}{dr}P(X \le rY | X = x)
$$

if $r \gt 0$
$$
= \frac{d}{dr}P(Y \ge \frac{x}{r}) = \\
\frac{d}{dr}(1 - F_Y(\frac{x}{r}) = \frac{x}{r^2}f_Y(\frac{x}{r}) ; x \ge 0
$$

if $r \lt 0$
$$
= \frac{d}{dr}P(Y \le \frac{x}{r}) = \\
\frac{d}{dr}F_Y(\frac{x}{r}) = \frac{-x}{r^2}f_Y(\frac{x}{r}) ; x \le 0
$$

So finally it is $ \frac{|x|}{r^2}f_Y(\frac{|x|}{r})$

Is this okay?  Or am I hopeless :|

Comment: Good work.  Problem 4 is _almost_ correct but not quite.  Let's focus on the case $r>0$.  Then you correctly derive $f_{R|X=x}(r|X=x)=\frac{x}{r^2}f_Y(x/r)$, and this holds for all $x$ (for some reason you put it only holds for $x\geq 0$).  Since $Y$ is non-negative we get $f_Y(y)=0$ for $y<0$, so: $$ f_{R|X=x}(r|X=x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} \frac{x}{r^2}f_Y(x/r) \quad \mbox{if $x\geq 0$}\\ 0 \quad \mbox{else} \\ \end{array} \right. $$

Comment: So putting both methods together should give the same answer, let's see:  The first method (conditioning on $Y=y$) yields: 
$$ f_R(r) = \int_0^{\infty} y f_X(ry)f_Y(y)dy $$ The second method of conditioning on $X=x$ (for $r>0$) gives: $$ f_R(r) = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x}{r^2}f_Y(x/r)f_X(x)dx $$ Using the change of variables $y=x/r$ and $dy = dx/r$ in the second integral shows it is indeed the same as the first!

Comment: (And your answers to problems 1-3 are correct).